# Technology to create clientless web video/audio

Tags: html, web, video-streaming, audio-streaming, instant-messaging

I am trying to create a video/audio IM chat on a website and struggling to find technology that can achieve this, but I know its out there somewhere. I have looked into Lync server but you must have to client on each computer for audio/video to work which is a big no no. I know it can be done because websites like chatroulette have done it, I just don't know how they do it.

Could anybody point me in the direction of a web API or technology that can achieve this? Thanks so much!

Comment: WebRTC is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of looking for anyone with a similar question, below are the best solutions:

- If you do not need IE compatibility then use WebRTC
- If you do need IE compatibility then use TokBox, but it does cost
- If you cannot afford to pay for TokBox, Flash or Silverlight using a server to setup peer to peer transmission is the best solution

I hope this helps!